Как передать русские символы из jsp в БД Sql Server
При заполнении БД (SQL Server) через jsp русскими словами, в БД они отображаются символами вроде этих: "& # 1085". Причём слова усекаются, когда нет для этого причины. Т.е. поле для ввода рассчитано на 30 символов, заполняю бд через jsp,например, словом "диван" и он усекает его, пишет символами в бд или вовсе не заносит его.
С английским языком всё в порядке, корректно отображается и работает.
Пыталась через добавление "useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf8" в строку соединения с БД, но не помогло.
На jsp странице также стоит:
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>

